# PhoneGap Windows Phone 8 IndexedDB AbortError when opening db

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, indexeddb

Using essentially the example from the [MDN IndexedDb tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) I can see that my test IndexedDb code is working on Chrome.  When I load the app onto my Windows Phone 8 device inside of the `deviceready` handler, I get an `AbortError` in the error handler for the database open request.

The only other related SO question was solved by fixing errors in `onupgradeneeded` but this handler is never even called in my code.

In this simple example, you have to run the fiddle twice because apparently `onsuccess` is called (where I read a test value) before `onupgradeneeded` (where I write the value when the db is initialized).  I was going to deal with this once I got this first test to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/WDUVx/2/

```
// In the following line, you should include the prefixes of
// implementations you want to test.
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

if (!window.indexedDB) {
  window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.");
}

// open the database
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 1);

request.onerror = function(e) {
  alert("Couldn't open database: " + kc.util.getObjectString(e.target));
};

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = e.target.result;
  var getRequest = 
   db.transaction("data")
  .objectStore("data")
  .get("firstObject")
  .onsuccess = function(event) {
    alert("Got: " + event.target.result.test);
  };
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("data", {
    autoincrement : false
  });

  objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
    var myObjectStore = db.transaction("data", "readwrite").objectStore("data");
    var addRequest = myObjectStore.add({
      test : true
      }, 
      "firstObject");

    addRequest.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Error adding");
    };

    addRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log("Added!");
    };
  };
};
```

Questions:

1. What is my stupid mistake?
2. Are there any Windows Phone 8 examples of IndexedDb and PhoneGap?  I could not find any after some searching. There were a few for an IndexedDb API Android and IOS polyfill, but none for wp8.
3. Is there something special that I have to do because I'm on a phone?  Again, the code works in chrome.
4. Are there any other plugins that support wp8 storage > 5mb?

   - LocalStorage has a 5mb size limit
   - WebSQL is not supported
   - FileSystem plugin does not support filewriter.write(blob). This is what I am using for Android/iOS.  It's strange that they say wp8 is supported by this plugin when <strike>this is the only way to actually write data, and you can't read the nothing you can write</strike>.   *I found that although the web api does not support it, the devices support* `filewriter.write(string)`. *Windows Phone 8 is still not writing/reading things entirely correctly, but that is a separate question.*

Comment: IDB should be fine storing much more than 5mb. Cordova does support IDB in WP8 so I'm curious about your issues. What is your protocol, domain and port tuple? I wonder if you're running into a security exception e.g. working off `file://`

Comment: I think it's using `file://` since all of my web assets are on the disk and wrapped with PhoneGap/Cordova.  It would help if the error thrown had any description other than 'AbortError', but unfortunately that's all I have to work with.  I'd expect a better error if it was security related, but that's certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I faced a similar issue with indexed DB. My IndexedDB.open request was throwing an abort error.

- After doing some search, I found suggestions to separate the requests for database creation and store creation.
- Separating the code prevented the abort error. However, I noticed that the transaction to create the stores was sometimes run even before the completion of the database creation request.
- This meant that my database connection was not closed from the first request, when the second request was run.
- A minor fix was required to overcome this error. I moved the code to create stores to the *success* event for the first call.

Here is the code for reference.

```
function create_db(db_name)
{
    var request = indexedDB.open(db_name);

request.onupgradeneeded=function(e)
{
     console.log("1. creating database");
     db=e.target.result;
 };

 request.onsuccess = function(e) 
 {
     db = e.target.result;
     console.log("1.1 database created successfully");
     db.close();
     add_tables(db_name);
 };

request.onerror=function(e)
 {
     alert("error: "+ e.target.error.name + "failed creating db");
     console.log("1.2 error creating db");
 }; 
}

function add_tables(db_name)
{
     var request = indexedDB.open(db_name,2);

     request.onsuccess=function(e)
 {
     db=e.target.result;
     console.log("2.2 table creation request successful");
 };

 request.onupgradeneeded=function(e)
 {
    db=e.target.result;

    table = db.createObjectStore("table_name");
    table.createIndex("id","id");       
    console.log("2.2 creating a single object store");
 };

request.onerror=function(e)
{
    console.log("2.3 error occured when creating tables");
};
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas, hope they help:

- Don't use a global db variable. Do all of your work in callbacks. Using a global db variable can lead to numerous in-explainable situations, some of which include getting abort errors. Looking at your code, it actually looks like you are properly just using e.target, so I am not sure why you have a global var db.
- Don't perform read/write requests on the version change transaction that occurs in the onupgradeneeded callback. Instead, perform requests when they are appropriate and let indexeddb worry about calling onupgradeneeded. In other words, don't retrieve the transaction in onupgradeneeded. Instead, just initiate some later transaction in a new connection as if the onupgradeneeded callback already completed.
- openDBRequest having an abort event precedes onupgradeneeded callback
- onupgradeneeded won't be called unless you make an attempt to connect to a database using a higher version
- Listen for abort events. Add a callback to the open database request for onabort. Abort events sometimes occur because of things like opening two pages in the same context that try to access the same database. There could be something funky going on there.